# How i can export string inside if to another if

Tags: php, html

hello guys how i can get string $test to another if

```
    if  (isset($_POST["but"])){
$test = 'website';
}
```

like this

```
    if  (isset($_POST["bu2t"])){
echo $test;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
$test = null;
if  (isset($_POST["but"])){
   $test = 'website';
}
```

And :

```
if(isset($_POST["bu2t"]))
{
    echo $test;
}
```

Comment: dosent work i dont know

Comment: Normal that `$_POST["bu2t"]` got this name instead of `$_POST["but2"]` ?

Comment: This should work as long as both `but` and `bu2t` POST variables are set. I think the problem is not the variable scope in your case.